# When running my program, I receive a message saying that "The Python REPL process has exited." Is this normal or not?

Tags: python, visual-studio, python-3.x, visual-studio-2015, python-imaging-library

I am running the program, attached below, and whenever I run it into Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013, I receive the following message: The Python REPL process has exited. I am very new to python and programming in general. The program is functioning as expected, but this message is making me worry. Is it normal or not? If it isn't normal, please advise me on how to fix this. I ran it using the native python idle, no error received, but still wondering if this could lead into an issue later. Just wondering if Visual Studio is trying to warn me of something that could happen if I was to extend this code. Command line gives just the output of the program.

```
from PIL import Image

class PixelCounter(object):
  ''' loop through each pixel and average rgb '''
  def __init__(self, imageName):
      self.pic = Image.open(imageName)
      #Opens image
      self.imgData = self.pic.load()
      # load image data
  def averagePixels(self):
      r, g, b = 0, 0, 0
      count = 0
      # Declares variables and sets them to 0 to be modified later
      for x in range(self.pic.size[0]):
          for y in range(self.pic.size[1]):
              tempr,tempg,tempb = self.imgData[x,y]
              r += tempr
              g += tempg
              b += tempb
              count += 1
              # Adds the rgb values of each pixel to the total r, g, b values
      ravg = r/count
      gavg = g/count
      bavg = b/count
      # calculates averages
      round(ravg)
      round(gavg)
      round(bavg)
      # Rounds numbers
      # print("R: ", ravg, ", G: ", gavg, ", B: ", bavg,", Total Pixels: ", count)
      # return (r/count), (g/count), (b/count), count

if __name__ == '__main__':
  # assumes you have a test.jpg in the working directory! 

  pc = PixelCounter("test.jpg")
  #print ("red, green, blue, total_pixel_count")
  print("R: ", ravg, ", G: ", gavg, ", B: ", bavg,", Total Pixels: ", count)
  #pc.averagePixels()
```

Comment: Try running it from command line and see what error it gives (probably not any).

Comment: I ran it using the native python idle, no error received, but still wondering if this could lead into an issue later. Just wondering if Visual Studio is trying to warn me of something that could happen if I was to extend this code. Command line gives just the output of the program.